# Echo with Shorthand If not behaving properly

Tags: php, shorthand-if

I'm programming in PHP, I'm using a 'shorthand if' to echo some HTML code on to the page, but it is behaving in odd ways.

```
echo '<div id="filter_bar">
<ul>';
    echo '<li><a href="?select=trending"' . ($_GET['select'] == "trending") ? ' class="filter_selected">Trending</a></li>' : '>Trending</a></li>';
    echo '<li><a href="?select=most_picked"' . ($_GET['select'] == "most_picked") ? ' class="filter_selected">Most Picked</a></li>' : '>Most Picked</a></li>';
    echo '<li><a href="?select=newest"' . ($_GET['select'] == "newest" || empty($_GET['select'])) ? ' class="filter_selected">Newest</a></li>' : '>Newest</a></li>';
echo '</ul></div>';
```

The resulting code that I get as a result is this

```
class="filter_selected">Trending</a></li> class="filter_selected">Most Picked</a></li> class="filter_selected">Newest</a></li>
```

As you can see, the opening list tags are not showing... but they do if I replace the first period '.' on each line with a ',' comma.

So this works, with the commas

Should I be using a comma here?  Everywhere online sheems to show a period '.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can make your life a bit easier:

```
echo '<div id="filter_bar"><ul>',
    '<li><a href="?select=trending"', $_GET['select'] == "trending" ? ' class="filter_selected">' : '>', 'Trending</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="?select=most_picked"', $_GET['select'] == "most_picked" ? ' class="filter_selected">' : '>', 'Most Picked</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="?select=newest"', ($_GET['select'] == "newest") || empty($_GET['select']) ? ' class="filter_selected">' : '>', 'Newest</a></li>',
'</ul></div>';
```

Which will use commas (no need to repeat echo that much) and you don't need to repeat strings that much if you only want to insert the class attribute.

Then you made use of parenthesis where they were not needed (see [Operator Precedence <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)) *but* at the place where those are needed, you didn't use them (the last case).

Additionally it's better to fill those values to variables upfront, so you can debug stuff easier (and you don't mix `$_GET` with output, so to prevent mixing output logic with input variables).

That done you could have learned that your issue is not within the `echo` but just the expression you've formulated with the ternary operator.

```
$class_trending = $_GET['select'] == "trending" ? ' class="filter_selected"' : '';
$class_most_picked = $_GET['select'] == "most_picked" ? ' class="filter_selected"' : '';
$class_newest = ($_GET['select'] == "newest") || empty($_GET['select']) ? ' class="filter_selected"' : '';

echo '<div id="filter_bar"><ul>',
    '<li><a href="?select=trending"', $class_trending, '>Trending</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="?select=most_picked"', $class_most_picked, '>Most Picked</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="?select=newest"',$class_newest , '>Newest</a></li>',
'</ul></div>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, may I ask what the difference between the commas and the periods are in this instance?  As I would usually use periods EG: `' . $class_trending . '` in the code you have posted above.  Is there any difference?

Comment: Using the `.` is concatenating the string before output. Using the comma is just outputting one string after the other (which suits your needs). Strictly spoken concatenating the string is not necessary prior output with echo (but can be done). Another benefit using `,`s is that you can use functions inside the `echo` statement which either return a string or echo themselves (which is not the case here, just FYI), so it can help to streamline the own code.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is:

`echo '<li>' . true ? 'aaa' : 'bbb';` will give you **aaa**,

because it is same with `'<li>1' ? 'aaa' : 'bbb'`

And you should do like this:
`echo '<li>' . (true ? 'aaa' : 'bbb');`

Answer (score 1):

dunno your problem but this code looks an ugly mess for me.
I'd make it this way:

in the PHP code I'd prepare variables first.

```
$sections = array(
  'newest'      => 'Newest',
  'trending'    => 'Trending',
  'most_picked' => 'Most Picked',
);
if (empty($_GET['select']) OR !$choice = array_search($sections,$_GET['select'])) {
  $choice = 'newest';
}
```

and then in the template run smooth and short loop:

```
<div id="filter_bar">
 <ul>
<? foreach ($sections as $sect => $name): ?>
  <li>
<a href="?select=<?=$sect?><? if ($choice == $sect) ?>" class="filter_selected"<? endif ?>><?=$name?></a>
  </li>
<? endforeach ?>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not rely on short_open_tag as this might be disabled.

Comment: ugh, just enable it. not a big deal

Comment: Just don't use it, not a big deal.

Comment: but I like it, short tags looks neat and require much less typing.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is

```
    echo "<li><a href='?select=newest'"; 
echo ($_GET['select'] == "newest" || empty($_GET['select'])) ? ' class="filter_selected">Newest</a></li>' : '>Newest</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your parentheses to the following:

```
echo '<div id="filter_bar">
<ul>';
    echo '<li><a href="?select=trending"' . ($_GET['select'] == "trending" ? ' class="filter_selected">Trending</a></li>' : '>Trending</a></li>');
    echo '<li><a href="?select=most_picked"' . ($_GET['select'] == "most_picked" ? ' class="filter_selected">Most Picked</a></li>' : '>Most Picked</a></li>');
    echo '<li><a href="?select=newest"' . (($_GET['select'] == "newest" || empty($_GET['select'])) ? ' class="filter_selected">Newest</a></li>' : '>Newest</a></li>');
echo '</ul></div>';
```

If you do not do this, PHP does not know what exactly your condition is. Also have a look at [operator precendence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) as this explains why it works using commas.

By the way: The ?: is called [ternary operator](http://ch.php.net/ternary).